# ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Optional Submodel With Required Property - Not Using Required though

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

I have the following finding received from Fortify on Demand:

ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Optional Submodel With Required Property

Here is a sample example of the code snippet that received the finding:

```
public interface IEditObjPermissionsItem : IErrorDictionary, IVrfyObject
{
    string EntityType { get; }
    int? foo { get; set; }
}
```

As the **REQUIRED** property was not used at all in the example, I am confused about the finding and think it may be another FP on the FoD side...

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. As there is no **[Required]** in any of the code, it is a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

The under-posting vulnerability would be if your child "submodel" contained the Required attribute.

> **Explanation**
>
> If a model class has required property and is the type of
> an optional member of a parent model class, it may be susceptible to
> under-posting attacks if an attacker communicates a request that
> contains less data than is expected.
>
> The ASP.NET MVC framework will try to bind request parameters to model
> properties, including submodels.
>
> If a submodel is optional -- that is, the parent model has a property
> without the [Required] attribute -- and if an attacker does not
> communicate that submodel, then the parent property will have a null
> value and the required fields of the child model will not be asserted
> by model validation. This is one form of an under-posting attack.

See: [VulnCat](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.dotnet.aspnet_mvc_bad_practices_optional_submodel_with_required_property#C%23%2fVB.NET%2fASP.NET)